# run function in the middle of superscrollorama parallax effect

Tags: javascript, events, animation, scroll, parallax

I'm using [superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/) and need to have an animation play once and then never again during the parallax. I could create a function to play the animation but it seems as though it only would work on completion of the parallax. Any thoughts or ideas would be helpful.

```
        controller.addTween('.div', (new TimelineLite()).append([
              TweenMax.from( $('.div .hero'), 1, 
                {css:{left:'1500', top:'-200'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}),
              TweenMax.fromTo($('.div .background'), 1, 
                {css:{left: -40}, immediateRender:true}, 
                {css:{left: -45}})
            ]),
          100 // scroll duration of tween
        );

        var oneTime = function(!firstime) {
            var firstime;
            TweenMax.from( $('.football'), .50, {
                css:{left:'1500', top:'-300'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut})
            ), 500, 500 ;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, TweenMax has a method onUpdate which would fire each time one of the properties is valid, and you can even tween any non-standard properties, so with that, you could just call your function, check against a value, and fire oneTime function when it resolves to true, and never do this again ..

It would look something like this:

```
TweenMax.fromTo($('.div .background'), 1, 
            {css:{left: -40}, immediateRender:true}, 
            {css:{left: -45}, onUpdate:oneTime,onUpdateParams: $(this).css('left')})
```

Does it help you this way?